# WiX Stock Images

Tags: wix

Wix has the ability to replace the stock images with custom ones http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/WixUI_dialog_library.htm

Is there any freely available sets of images for installers to use if the WiX stock ones don't suit our style.

As being a programmer I should play to my strengths and not try to be a graphic designer when I'm not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any.  I rolled my own using Paint.NET for IsWiX but usually I just provide the images to my clients ( or management ) and let them get fancy.  It's their branding after all not mine.